# Test email does not arrive in mail.outbox when sent by Django-RQ worker

Tags: python, django, python-rq, django-rq, rq

I've set up a test within `Django` that sends an email, in the background, using `Django-RQ`.

I call the code that enqueues the `send_email` task, then, I get the `django-rq` worker, and call .work(), with `burst=True`.

In my console, I can see the `django-rq` worker picking up the job, and confirming that it's been processed successfully. However, the email never arrives in Django's test `mail.outbox`.

Here is the test code:

```py
    def test_reset_password(self):
        c = Client()
        page = reverse_lazy("accounts:password_reset")
        response = c.post(page, {'email': 'joe@test.co.uk'})
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse_lazy("accounts:login"), 302, 200)
        
        django_rq.get_worker(settings.RQ_QUEUE).work(burst=True)

        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
        self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].subject, 'Password reset instructions')
```

And here's the output from the console when the test is run:

```bash
Found 2 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.Worker rq:worker:0e599ef7e7e34e30a1b753678777b831: started, version 1.12.0
Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:0e599ef7e7e34e30a1b753678777b831
*** Listening on default...
Cleaning registries for queue: default
default: send() (214c3a65-c642-49f2-a832-cb40750fad2a)
default: Job OK (214c3a65-c642-49f2-a832-cb40750fad2a)
Result is kept for 500 seconds
Worker rq:worker:0e599ef7e7e34e30a1b753678777b831: done, quitting
Unsubscribing from channel rq:pubsub:0e599ef7e7e34e30a1b753678777b831
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_reset_password (accounts.tests.AccountsTest.test_reset_password)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/accounts/tests.py", line 30, in test_reset_password
    self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 1.686s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Is it possible the email is going to a different instance of the `django.core.mail.mailbox` ? and if so, is there an effective way to unit test emails, in this context ?